# Splitting __m256 into two __m128 registers

Tags: c, intrinsics, avx, avx2

I have one `__m256` containing 8 floats, and I'd like to split this into 2  `__m128`, one containing the first four floats and the other containing the last four floats. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What reference are you using to learn about AVX programming?

Comment: I'm looking through Intels documentation on https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/ . I thought of loading the first 128 bits, then shifting then loading the first 128 bits again but that didn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: For instance, selecting just the AVX instructions, and searching __m128d, gives a list of less than 20 instructions, easy enough to check those with a likely name.

Answer (score 6):

`_mm256_extractf128_ps` can be used for both the upper and lower parts. For the upper part, that's the best way to extract it. However, with some slightly older versions of MSVC that intrinsic always results in the corresponding instruction, even when the index is zero (in that case actually *no instruction* is necessary). So for extracting the lower part, `_mm256_castps256_ps128` should be preferred.